# How to make find and printf works in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My environment: Linux Redhat, Bash 3.5

I have created a bash script to list all of files in sub directories using script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ); do
    b=$(echo $i | awk '{print substr($1,3); }' )
    find $i -type f > $i/$b.txt
done
```

I want to add `sha1sum` to my script, I've edit it as shown below.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ); do
    b=$(echo $i | awk '{print substr($1,3); }' )
    find $i -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -printf "%b:" -exec sha1sum -b {} \; > ./$i/$b.txt
done
```

The second code is failed with error below

`No such file or directory`

Comment: Run your script as `bash -x ./script.sh` and paste the debug output here.

Comment: Maybe the error is due to `./$i/$b.txt`. Remove the leading `./` and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify in what way your attempt failed [See note 1, below], I've just provided some thoughts about how to solve the underlying question of producing lists of checksums for each directory.

Your use of `find` is both unnecessary and unsafe (if there are any directories whose names include whitespace or shell metacharacters.

For example,

```
$( find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d )
```

is roughly the same as the "glob"

```
./*/
```

except that the glob does not perform pathname expansion or word-splitting on the individual directories. Furthermore, you could use the glob `*/`, which will avoid the `./` prefix, which you evidently don't want.

Also,

```
b=$(echo $i | awk '{print substr($1,3); }' )
```

could be written much more simply as

```
b=${i:3}   # Bash substring notation
```

or

```
b=${i#./}  # Posix standard prefix deletion
```

But, as noted above, you could use a glob and thereby avoid any having to remove the prefix.

So you could have simply written:

```
#!/bin/bash
for b in */; do
    find "$b" -type f > "$b/$b.txt"
done
```

Note the quotes around the variable expansions. If you really need the `%b` format to print filenames, then you definitely need to quote the expansions to avoid problems with whitespace and shell metacharacters, but anyway you should develop the a habit of quoting variable expansions.

That will produce a slightly different output than your script since it doesn't place the `./` at the beginning of each line in the output file, but if you really wanted that you could use `find "./$b" ...`.

I don't understand why you feel the need to use `printf` to output the filename for the SHA-1 checksums, because `sha1sum` already prints the filename. It's true that it does so after the checksum instead of before. There is actually a good reason for that behaviour: since there is no way of knowing what characters the filename might include, putting the checksum first makes it easier to parse the output.

Note that in the output of `sha1sum`, the output for each file whose name includes a backslash or newline, the checksum line will start with a backslash and the backslash and newline characters in the filename will be escaped. This produces an effect somewhat similar to that of using the `%b` format to printf.

If you really want to turn the order around, you can do so easily enough with awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
for b in */; do
    find "$b" -type f '!' -iname '*thumbs.db*' -exec sha1sum {} + |
    awk '{print "$2:$1"}' > "$b/$b.txt"
done
```

Using `+` instead of `;` to terminate the `-exec` option lets `find` execute the command with a list of filenames instead of just a single filename, which is much more efficient.

---

#### Notes

1. See the [Stack Overflow help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), from which I quote:

   > Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

   "It doesn't work" is *not* a "specific problem or error". You should always include the literal text of the error message or a clear statement of how the result of the program failed to meet your expectations.

Comment: Dear Rici, i get the error 'code' ./yyy.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/yyy.sh: line 2: `for b in */; do
'code'

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings; remove them with `dos2unix`.